# Get scroll event without anything to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a website which has a scroll to go to the next link functionality. Because I am using overflow:hidden on my container, there is no scroll to detect, which give me trouble triggering the actual link to the other page.

Now to tackle this problem I had downloaded a plugin called jQuery Mousewheel which checks of the mousewheel is used. Problem is that on mobile it does not work, because there is no mousewheel there.

I checked the github: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel/issues/56 and they say to go to another plugin because this is not in the scope.

Well how and what plugin or code do I need to use to make it work? I want to catch the scroll event without actually scrolling because there is nothing to scroll due to overflow:hidden.

At this moment I use this code to trigger the scroll down to go to the next page:

```
jQuery('.front.intro').on('mousewheel scroll touchmove', function(event) {
            //console.log(event.deltaX, event.deltaY, event.deltaFactor);

            if(event.deltaY < 0){
                console.log("downscroll");
               $('#scrolldownbtn').trigger('click');
            }
        });
```

EDIT: Made it work after removing the deltaY check from the code. It doesn't check for downscroll now, but that is the tradeoff I'm willing to make.

Comment: Is your code currently working? Because I think `touchmove` is the way to go... Maybe it doesn't have `deltaY` in the event?

Comment: Nope, it does not have Delta Y in the event. I made it work after removing the deltaY from the code. I guess every scroll movement, up or down triggers the call. Not perfectly, but it works so I'm rolling with it now.

Comment: You can listen to the `touchmove` event on touch-based devices, for example, and set a threshold so that only a large-enough movement along perhaps a specific axis will trigger your callback/method.